# TFS and git, missing referece

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio, tfs

For example in asp.net mvc project when I pull repositories, some references are missing.

I must adding them again manually. In small projects is not a problem but in huge repositories it is occurred as big problem and time lost. Also the same problem exists in git. I want when I pull repositories everything should be clear.

Is there a any solution about this problem ?

Comment: Nuget Restore is not pulling them ?

Comment: I just go to source control panel. Right click project what ı want then click "Get Latest version. Are you mean that In package Manager Console, am I writing pull command ?

Comment: Assuming the reference were added via nuget (there will be a packages.config file), just right click the solution and do "Restore nuget packages".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking from a "best practices" point of view, your source control should not contain the libraries on which your project depends.  Instead it should contain the instructions for obtaining those dependencies (such as references in your project definition files).

How seamlessly this works depends on your tooling.  In Visual Studio development environments typically you use NuGet, and unfortunately in my experience you have to actually tell NuGet you want your references resolved.  (By contrast, for projects using Maven dependency management - more common in Java than .Net - resolution of dependencies is a default part of the build lifecycle; so you can just check out and build.)

To fully implement the best practices I mention... is not always trivial.  You might find you'd need to host your own NuGet packages, for example.  There are benefits to following through on that, but not everyone decides to.

Anyway, though I don't recommend it, for completeness in answering the question as asked, here's an alternative.  It seems you're initially talking about Visual Studio, Team Explorer, and TFVC.

It is *possible* to embed referenced libs in the source control.  Typically the directories where these libs live in the work tree are ignored by the source control, so a default attempt to "add everything to source control" may pass over them.  If you navigate to the specific libs in your solution explorer, and specifically say to add just those files, you'd be prompted "file is ignored; add anyway" (or something like that).  And if you say yes, then that's that.

As for why this would also happen with git... well, I assume you're using the same tooling (visual studio / team explorer) to address git, and I assume by default they set up the same ignore rules.  It's a tool combination I don't really use, so I can't say anything more definite than that.

Now, I have projects with a mix of NuGet and source-control-embedded libraries, and I can tell you I'd take NuGet (even with the extra step of telling it I need dependencies resolved) any day of the week.

Comment: Thank you for helpful answer. It is good idea that is ignoring source control for libs.